# Query param not behaving as expected

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfqueryparam

I'm using an `:order` query param to pass an order argument to my function. Unfortunately, it seems not to have an effect on the output.

The request debugging output shows the `order` argument is parsed correctly:

`Parameter #2(cf_sql_varchar) = posts.createdAt ASC`

Yet it still makes no difference to output. If I hard code the argument (`ORDER BY ..., #arguments.order#`), it works fine.

Any ideas?

```
public any function getPost(required numeric postId, string order)
{
    switch(arguments.order)
    {
        case "new":
            arguments.order = "posts.createdAt DESC";
            break;
        case "old": 
            arguments.order = "posts.createdAt ASC";
            break;
        default:
            arguments.order = "posts.score DESC";
    }

    local.post = new Query(dataSource=variables.wheels.class.connection.datasource);
    local.post.setSql("
        SELECT *
        FROM
        WHERE posts.id = :postId OR posts.parentId = :postId
        ORDER BY posts.postTypeId ASC, :order"
    );

    local.post.addParam(name="postId", cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer", value=arguments.postId, maxlength=10);
    local.post.addParam(name="order", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar", value=arguments.order, maxlength=20);
    local.post = local.post.execute().getResult();

    return local.post;
```

}

Comment: just a guess, try using a name other than "order", wondering if that's a keyword that the parser chokes on.

Comment: Can you even use bind variables in the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: @orangepips @Al Everett, that would be a no! It appears Al is right that you can't bind params to the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, queryparams won't work anywhere except in the where clause. So you're not dealing with a bug, but a limitation.

Comment: I think that queryParam is only used to insert dynamics values in a where clause.
Personnally, for this kind of situation I do a concatenation like setQuery(" ... " & orderyBy)

Comment: You can use queryparams in join statements or in the select list as well.  They are limited to where you would be able to put a SQL variable in the query (since that is what ColdFusion is doing with queryparams behind the scenes).